# OSError: There was a specific connection error when trying to load CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4: <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

#### System Info

Google Colab, Free version, GPU

#### Information

- [ ] The official example scripts
- [X] My own modified scripts

#### Tasks

- [ ] An officially supported task in the `examples` folder (such as GLUE/SQuAD, ...)
- [X] My own task or dataset (give details below)

#### Reproduction

1. https://github.com/woctezuma/stable-diffusion-colab
2. https://colab.research.google.com/github/woctezuma/stable-diffusion-colab/blob/main/stable_diffusion.ipynb#scrollTo=GR4vF2bw-sHR
3. copy create to drive
4. run 1st cell
5. run 2nd cell
6. copy my token from  https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens
7. paste it to the filed
8. press enter
9. #1st error - https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/invalid-token-passed/22711
10. https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens mange invalidate and refres
11. run 2nd cell again
12. copy and paste in new token

```
        _|    _|  _|    _|    _|_|_|    _|_|_|  _|_|_|  _|      _|    _|_|_|      _|_|_|_|    _|_|      _|_|_|  _|_|_|_|
        _|    _|  _|    _|  _|        _|          _|    _|_|    _|  _|            _|        _|    _|  _|        _|
        _|_|_|_|  _|    _|  _|  _|_|  _|  _|_|    _|    _|  _|  _|  _|  _|_|      _|_|_|    _|_|_|_|  _|        _|_|_|
        _|    _|  _|    _|  _|    _|  _|    _|    _|    _|    _|_|  _|    _|      _|        _|    _|  _|        _|
        _|    _|    _|_|      _|_|_|    _|_|_|  _|_|_|  _|      _|    _|_|_|      _|        _|    _|    _|_|_|  _|_|_|_|

        To login, `huggingface_hub` now requires a token generated from https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens .
        
Token: 
Login successful
Your token has been saved to /root/.huggingface/token
Authenticated through git-credential store but this isn't the helper defined on your machine.
You might have to re-authenticate when pushing to the Hugging Face Hub. Run the following command in your terminal in case you want to set this credential helper as the default

git config --global credential.helper store
```

13. I have run `git config --global credential.helper store` than I could  rerun everything and move forward 2 cells
14. Cell CODE

```
import mediapy as media
import torch
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

model_id = "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4"
device = "cuda"
remove_safety = False


pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, scheduler=scheduler, torch_dtype=torch.float16, revision="fp16", use_auth_token=True)
if remove_safety:
  pipe.safety_checker = lambda images, clip_input: (images, False)
pipe = pipe.to(device)
```

15. ERROR

```
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in raise_for_status(self)
    940         if http_error_msg:
--> 941             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    942 

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4/resolve/fp16/model_index.json

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

HfHubHTTPError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/diffusers/configuration_utils.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    233                     subfolder=subfolder,
--> 234                     revision=revision,
    235                 )

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in hf_hub_download(repo_id, filename, subfolder, repo_type, revision, library_name, library_version, cache_dir, user_agent, force_download, force_filename, proxies, etag_timeout, resume_download, use_auth_token, local_files_only, legacy_cache_layout)
   1056                     proxies=proxies,
-> 1057                     timeout=etag_timeout,
   1058                 )

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_hf_file_metadata(url, use_auth_token, proxies, timeout)
   1358     )
-> 1359     hf_raise_for_status(r)
   1360 

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_errors.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in hf_raise_for_status(response, endpoint_name)
    253         # as well (request id and/or server error message)
--> 254         raise HfHubHTTPError(str(HTTPError), response=response) from e
    255 

HfHubHTTPError: <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'> (Request ID: esduBFUm9KJXSxYhFffq4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
[<ipython-input-6-9b05f13f8bf3>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>
      9 
     10 
---> 11 pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, scheduler=scheduler, torch_dtype=torch.float16, revision="fp16", use_auth_token=True)
     12 if remove_safety:
     13   pipe.safety_checker = lambda images, clip_input: (images, False)

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/diffusers/pipeline_utils.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    371                 local_files_only=local_files_only,
    372                 use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
--> 373                 revision=revision,
    374             )
    375             # make sure we only download sub-folders and `diffusers` filenames

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/diffusers/configuration_utils.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    254             except HTTPError as err:
    255                 raise EnvironmentError(
--> 256                     "There was a specific connection error when trying to load"
    257                     f" {pretrained_model_name_or_path}:\n{err}"
    258                 )

OSError: There was a specific connection error when trying to load CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4:
<class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'> (Request ID: esduBFUm9KJXSxYhFffq4)
```

#### Expected behavior

Run all the cells and generating photo's as on the GitHub project shows
https://github.com/woctezuma/stable-diffusion-colab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go to the huggingface website and agree the terms.

https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4

you need to be logged into your hugging face account.